# are tensorflow operations pointwise?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

If I do the following:

```
r = (x - mn) / std
```

where x is of shape (batchSize, 100), mn, and std are all of length (1, 100)

Are the subtraction and division done pointwise?  I would expect to r to be (batchSize, 100).

I cannot examine the shapes directly because using tf.keras.batch_flatten obliberates the shapes.

For example:

```
x.shape
TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(314), Dimension(314), Dimension(8)])

x = K.batch_flatten(x)
<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_1/activity_regularizer/Reshape_2:0' shape=(?, ?) dtype=float32>

x.shape
TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything concerning `Keras` and `Tensorflow` is `Numpy` compatible as it could be. So let's have a look.

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
m = np.array([1,1,1,1,1])
n = np.array([5,4,3,2,1])
std = 10
m_times_n = m * n
# [5 4 3 2 1]
x_minus_mn = x - m_times_n
# [-4 -2  0  2  4]
r = x_minus_mn / std
# [-0.4 -0.2  0.   0.2  0.4]
```

So they are pointwise. Or let's see what happens in `Tensorflow`:

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()
x = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5])
m = tf.constant([1,1,1,1,1])
n = tf.constant([5,4,3,2,1])
std = tf.constant(10)
m_times_n = m * n
# tf.Tensor([5 4 3 2 1], shape=(5,), dtype=int32)
x_minus_mn = x - m_times_n
# tf.Tensor([-4 -2  0  2  4], shape=(5,), dtype=int32)
r = x_minus_mn / std
# tf.Tensor([-0.4 -0.2  0.   0.2  0.4], shape=(5,), dtype=float64)
```

Pointwise as well.

---

Also in your post you have mentioned that you have issues with `tf.keras.batch_flatten`. The resulting `(?, ?)` shape is because of the way  `tf.keras.batch_flatten` works. Let's have a look:

```
# Assuming we have 5 images, with 320x320 size, and 3 channels
X = tf.ones((5, 320,320, 3))
flatten = tf.keras.backend.batch_flatten(X)
flatten.shape
# (5, 307200)
```

Taken from the documentation:

> Turn a nD tensor into a 2D tensor with same 0th dimension.

And we are seeing the exact thing. The `0th (batch_size)` has been kept, while all other dimensions were squeezed such that the resulting tensor is 2D.

Comment: "Everything concerning Keras and Tensorflow is Numpy compatible" is this fact documented anywhere?

Comment: Also, why does batch_flatten obliterate the shape?  It clearly knows all the dimensions but the first which is the batch size.

Comment: @Avedis Although not a fact, usually you can recreate the same operations with Numpy the same way as you do them in Tensorflow.

Comment: Idk about your second point though, if I have a look at the whole code maybe I will figure it out.

Comment: I updated the question to be more general so that its more helpful.

Comment: Ok, Included an explanation for 
`tf.keras.backend.batch_flatten` here as well so the answer will be more elaborate. Besides, I also have an explanation for `tf.keras.backend.batch_flatten` in your other recent question.

Comment: I dont get the result you get regarding batch_flatten when I use keras.  Why is that?  Also, where are you finding this documentation?

Comment: Here is the link: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/batch_flatten

Comment: Thank you.  Its interesting that I dont get the same answer with pure keras.  Should I be use that or tf.keras?

Comment: I would go for tf.keras